# Custom spinner text view not coming properly

Tags: android, spinner

I have used custom spinner's `TextView` but its coming like below,

[image]

I haven't used `android:paddingRight=""` then also don't know why its coming like this.
The year which i am trying to show is coming in dot lines.

**spinner_textview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16.0dip"
android:gravity="left"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: set `android:padding="5dip"` to TextVIew

Comment: try to make custom spinner background as 9patch so it can auto adjust as spinner item text...

Comment: Width of the spinner is not enough for the text to fit, change/increase the layout_width for the spinner, try it in fixed "dp"s to get an idea of what is happening

Comment: @PankajKumar: when i am using `5dip` the text is getting disappear and   when i am making upto till 1dip then its coming but dots are coming

Comment: Ok then Spinner didn't get enough space to show your content. Move both Spinner to below of TextView. Like Expiry_date should be on top and both spinner should be below

Comment: @PankajKumar: Can i use `ellipsize` in TextView of Spinner ?

Comment: That is done by default as you attached image.

Comment: @PankajKumar: don't get your point ?

Comment: ellipsize is done by default (as you can see ... at last of 20) so there is no any benefit you will get after using ellipsize

Comment: @PankajKumar: are you talking about down arrow image..yes its coming by default but ellipsize(marquee) is not by default.

Comment: @PankajKumar: I am saying about `ellipsize(maarquee)` effect ?

Comment: @PankajKumar: if its by default. So, can we override that ellipsize and change it to marquee ?

Comment: You can use maarquee ellipsize, if your design need it. But beeter is to break label top and Spinners bottom

Comment: @PankajKumar: Please see my edits. I tried to use that but not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46815/discussion-between-android-and-pankaj-kumar)

Comment: @PankajKumar: I have seen it in one app and in that app they use marquee in Spinner text..that why I am confused how they done that..

Answer (score 0):

set **android:ellipsize** to **none**. I think you get the problem solved.

Comment: what if I want to use ellipsize (Marquee) in spinner's TextView ?

Comment: for ellipsize (Marquee), its generating **...** at the end of TextView.

Comment: that dot's problem is already solved. please see comment in my post..
i want marquee text means moving text.